# My text area will not get larger when I change the number of columns

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have an html textarea that is coded like this in php:

```
<textarea rows="8" cols="500" id="note1" name="note1"></textarea></p>
```

My problem is I keep upping the col number and it is stuck looking like this:

[image]

How can I get the text area to span to fill the area. I do not like all that white space on the right...

Comment: Just style the width/height via CSS.. http://jsfiddle.net/DdPRN/

Comment: What's with the backslashes?

Comment: @j08691 am sure he is echoing... -OP use `width: 100%`

Comment: @j08691 To escape the double quotes for the PHP?

Comment: @JoshC I thought the same, but again, one double quote is unescaped

Comment: Then post the PHP or the rendered HTML, not this frankenstein hybrid. This doesn't have anything to do with PHP anyway so just post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Aside from all that, there is a stray double quote in there that isn't escaped.. May be the problem.. though that would cause a PHP error. As a suggestion - rather than escaping them, just use single quotes instead.

Comment: I changed the code to just the html from the php

Comment: @Mike `cols`/`rows` are relative to font-size. Just use the `width`/`height` property instead.

Comment: Just tried this: <textarea style=\width: 100%; "  id="note1" name="note1"></textarea></p> and it didnt work

Comment: @Mike You're doing it wrong - http://jsfiddle.net/zCDcg/

Answer (score 0):

Check your DOM, I think this textarea is inheriting the form's width attribute.